# SQL Server table design advice for linking 3 Entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have three entities *Plan, Feature, Sensor* represented by tables using the same structure as follows:

```
[Entity]
--------
Id (int)
Name (varchar)
```

Each entity links to the other with 1-many relationships:

Each *Plan* can have multiple *Feature*s

Each *Feature* can have multiple *Sensor*s (note that different features may have common sensors, but have different requirement levels - optional/mandatory)

This data will be used inside an application where the user will select a plan and ultimately will be shown a list of required sensors.

**Design Issue #1:**

I firstly want to have a table that will describe relationship between *Plan* and *Feature* and my though is to have a table:

```
PlanFeatures
--------------
PlanId (int)
FeatureId (int)
Required (bit)
```

If I have a *Required* column then I will effectively need to have a record for each combination of *PlanId* and *FeatureId*. The alternative is to only add a record if the *PlanId and FeatureId* combination exists. Which is better?

**Design Issue #2**

Similarly to #1, I want to have a table that describes the relationship between *Features and Sensors* with the only difference being that a *Sensor* may be either not required/optional/mandatory. So the idea is to have a table as follows:

```
FeatureSensors
--------------
FeatureId(int)
SensorId(int)
RequirementLevel(int)
```

As for #1, I am questioning whether I need to have a record for each combination of *FeatureId and SensorId* and if it is not needed then I just use a 0 for the *RequirementLevel*, otherwise I only have a record where it is optional (1) or mandatory (2).

Am I going down the right path here or is there a much better way to structure this data?

Comment: Can a `Feature` belong to multiple `Plan`? If not then you don't need another table anyway. If yes, I'd advise to only have a record if it needs to exist, and don't have `Required`. In the second case: same questions. And I'd advise just `Optional` and `Mandatory` levels

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is definitely one way to do it, on principle. Connecting tables via "relational tables" (EDIT: Don't know whether there's an official name for these) is a known practice.

Even before I finished reading, I asked myself the same question you did regarding issue #1: Why would you need a record for each combination of plan and feature? Similarly, why would you need a record for each combination of feature and requirement? I'd simply store the combinations that are actually applied in practice in the database, and not store the combinations that aren't used at all.

The requirement level (optional/mandatory) can then be stored as a boolean flag; i.e. maybe rename it to "required_flag" or something like that. If the flag is set to true, the feature/sensor is required for the plan/feature, respectively. If the flag is false, the combination is optional. This way, you also have a uniform presentation of requirement levels in both tables.